# Angular router navigation with human readable name instead of id

Tags: javascript, angular

In an application router URL needs to be displayed with names instead of ids.

Like `http://localhost/myproject/statename/districtname`

instead of `http://localhost/myproject/stateid/districid`

User will first select state and then district from the list to reach in this navigation.
Though Angular will internally hold the current state id and current district id.

Is it possible any way to make URL in this way in Angular (not in version 1)?

Comment: Short answer: Yes!!! Longer: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
Configuring route:

```
       {
            path: 'test/:value',
            component: component
        }
```

Calling route:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['test/param']"> testRoute</a>
```

Accessing it in component:

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.value = params['value'];
        if (this.value !== undefined && this.value != null) {
              //your business logic
        }

    });
```

}

Hope it helps!!